# How to do simple slope analysis for interactions in zero-inflated negative binomial regression in r?

Tags: r, interaction, negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

I used the function 'zeroinfl' from the 'pscl' package to fit a zero-inflated model with negative binomial distribution (zinb). Results show significant interaction effects and I should do simple slope analyses for some of the interactions.

The packages I have tried to use for simple slope analysis (jtools, sjPlot, rockchalk, multcomp, QuantPsyc) however, cannot handle zero-inflated models. (Most of them can be used for lm, glm, but not for zinb models).

1. Does anyone know a package that I could use for zinb?
2. Alternatively, is there an easy way to calculate and test simple slopes in zinb?

Below is my model, where Gender is a factor with 2 levels,

A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H are continuous variables, all centered.

I want to do simple slope tests for the count model for

E x Gender,

F x Gender,

H x Gender

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Is coding the analysis yourself an option? Since you have a binary predictor, it shouldn't be too difficult.